# How to find table row id when knowing href of td contains specific text by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have rows in this format:

```
   <tr id="_ctl0_viewCompanies_companyRepeater_myresultsRow1_13" class="DGAlternatingItemStyle">
    <td style="padding:0.5em;">
<a style="color: #8B0000; font-size: 1em; font-weight:normal;" href="http://mylinkhere?itemid=12367" target="_blank">some name text</a>
</td>
```

I know this part `itemid=12367` in href is unique, how could I find the id of tr contains that itemid ? (the result should be: `_ctl0_viewCompanies_companyRepeater_myresultsRow1_13` )
What I tried:

```
 function getAllElementsWithAttribute()
{
  var matchingElements = [];
  var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
  for (var i = 0, n = allElements.length; i < n; i++)
  {
    if (allElements[i].getAttribute("href"))
    {
      // Element exists with attribute. Add to array.
      matchingElements.push(allElements[i]);
    }
  }
  alert ( matchingElements );
}
```

But I not sure what else to do from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  [jQuery ends with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selecter

```
 $('a[href$="itemid=12367"]').closest('tr').attr('id')
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/5u3rncvy/3/)

Comment: Then can I use it directly from codebehind? for example: lnk.Attributes.Add("onClick", " window.scroll(0, document.getElementById($('a[href$='itemid=12367']').closest('tr').attr('id')).offsetTop + screen.height);return false;"); ? I tried this but seems there is error somewhere..

Comment: the link button is created in code behind: LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton(); lnk.ID = "lnk" + listItemIds; lnk.Text = arrProcess[ar]; lnk.Attributes.Add("onClick", "linkClick('itemid=12367')"); I make as you suggestion but when I click on link there is nothing happens. What I want is create link and when I click on that link it will scroll to the row having that ID. I dont know the ID of that row but I know that row contains a td with href that have unique text "itemid=12367".

Comment: It will be helpful if you could post a demo `fiddle` or share your html & script code .Try this http://jsfiddle.net/5u3rncvy/11/

Answer (score 3):

You can use the attribute contains selector to get the anchor with that unique part of the href, then get the closest TR

```
$('a[href*="itemid=12367"]').closest('tr').prop('id')
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8201w8g6/)

Comment: Why the result is "some name text", not "_ctl0_viewCompanies_companyRepeater_myresultsRow1_13" which is what I want to get?

Comment: There's no way you would get the elements text when using the code above ?